# What would be the best way to sort events according to its date

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactjs

I have array with a few hundred `events` where every has date entry (in `Date().getTime` format in **DB**) and I have *10 days* displayed in simple table. To every day-row I need to display number of events in that particular day. What would be the best way to do that?

Okay here is an update:

I've Firebase db with this structure:

```
{
  events: {
    event1: {
      date: 144335265211,
      title: "sometext",
      text: "longer text"
      },
    event2: {
      date: 1444482619766,
      title: "sometext",
      text: "longer text"
      }
    }
 }
```

I am pulling it into local Redux store so I have an JS array with the same structure.

This way I am creating the table for particular days:

```
for (let dc = 0; dc < 10; dc++) {
     const date = new Date();
     date.setDate(date.getDate() + dc);
     const m = date.getMonth();
     const d = date.getDay();
     const y = date.getUTCFullYear();
      rows.push(
        <td>"On the " + m + "/" + d + "/" + y + " is SOMENUMBER events"</td>
      );
   return rows;
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Could you please include some code, such as a [mcve]?

Comment: the elements are getting pulled from a database? Which database are you using? Please explain what you're after so we can help. The question as it stands now is not answerable!

Comment: data shown isn't array, it's an object. Will need another object that uses dates as keys and has array for value to put the events into as start point, then probably take that and convert to array or whatever you need it to be

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl! Wouldn't you mind to outline a quick example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert it to an array:

```
var events = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  return Object.assign({}, obj[key], {eventName: key});
});
```

Then you need to group them by date. We can do this with lodash.

```
var groupBy = require('lodash/collection/groupBy');

var eventsWithDay = events.map((event) => {
  return Object.assign({}, event, {day: new Date(event.date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
});

var byDay = groupBy(eventsWithDay, 'day');
```

And byDay will be an object with a key for each date with a value of an array of events for that day.

Comment: Thanks [FakeRainBrigand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1074592/fakerainbrigand) this helped a lot! I tried to use countBy instead of groupBy to directly output the number of events count in each day. Great!